# SAS: Converting the date format from yymmdd10. to date9

Tags: sas

I have a sas dataset with a column called "date" in the format of yymmdd10., such as 2022-05-24.

I tried to covert it into the format of date9. as below, but it returns missing.

```
data want;
set have;
date1 = input(date,yymmdd10.);
format date1 date9. 
run;
```

So I'd like to know what is the right code. Thanks!

Comment: If you already have date values in the variable there is nothing to "convert".  Just attach a different format with a FORMAT statement and the values will be displayed differently. If you don't have date values in the current variable then describe what type of values you do have.  Is it a character variable (which your posted code is assuming) or a numeric variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do have the date values already, so it worked when I format the date by using "date1=put(date, date9.)".

Comment: Did you really want to create DATE1 as a character string?  Wouldn't it be better to make it as a date value instead?  `date1=date; format date1 date9.;`

Comment: You're right. I want to create the date value instead of the character string. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date '24MAY2022'd is the number 22,790. To have it display as 24MAY2022 instead of 2022-05-24 just change the format used to display it.

```
data want;
  set have;
  format date date9. ;
run;
```

Your code is treating DATE as if it was a character variable.  So SAS will first convert the number 22,790 into a string using the BEST12. format.  Since your informat has a width of only 10 the INPUT() function will try to convert the first 10 characters of the 12 character string        `22790`. But the string `227` cannot be interpreted as a date by that informat, hence the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the appearance of the date in the data set without recreating the data set using PROC DATASETS.

```
title 'Initial format';
proc print data=have(obs=5);
var date;
run;

*modify format;
proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
modify have;
format date date9.;
run;quit;

title 'New format';
proc print data=have(obs=5);
var date; 
run;
```